# Supporting webpack dependant imports during node dev server execution (a React server rendering context)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have a universal React project configured in which I use Webpack to create bundles for both the *client* and the *server* code.

This works fine when I run the server directly via the targetting the bundled output by Webpack.

```
 node ./build/server/main.js
```

However I am having issues though when I try to run a "live" development server.  In this case I don't want to target the bundled server files, instead I just target the source files directly which will allow me to run the webpack hot middleware for live code changes.  Below is a stripped down version of the main file for the server.

---

**src/server/index.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import universalReactAppMiddleware from './middleware/universalReactApp'

const server = express()

// Get the client bundle webpack configuration.
const webpackClientConfig = require('../../webpack.client.config.js')

// If we are in development mode we will add the webpack hot 
// reloading middleware.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const webpack = require('webpack')
  const clientCompiler = webpack(webpackClientConfig)
  const createWebpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
  const createWebpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
  server.use(
    createWebpackMiddleware(clientCompiler, {
      noInfo: true,
      publicPath: webpackClientConfig.output.publicPath,
      stats: {
        colors: true,
        hash: false,
        timings: true,
        chunks: false,
        chunkModules: true,
        modules: false
      }
    })
  )
  server.use(
    createWebpackHotMiddleware(clientCompiler)
  )
}

// Configure static serving of our webpack bundled client files.
server.use(
  webpackClientConfig.output.publicPath,
  express.static(webpackClientConfig.output.path))

// Bind our universal react app middleware for all GET requests.
server.get('*', universalReactAppMiddleware)

server.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT)
```

---

An example execution of this now being:

```
NODE_ENV=development babel-node ./src/server
```

It starts up okay, but the moment the `universalReactAppMiddleware` handles a request it will attempt to perform server rendering for a resolved Component. This then falls over because some of my components import images/css, for example:

---

**src/shared/components/Foo**

```
import './styles.css'
import background from './background.jpg'

function FooComponent() {
  return <img src={background} />
}
```

---

Computer says no!

Upon execution my express server throws out an exception saying unexpected syntax.  It basically tries to parse the css and image imports as Javascript.  These types of imports depend on my webpack loaders to operate correctly.

---

So now I am trying to look for a mechanism of spoofing the Webpack behaviour so that I can execute these types of components.  I am investigating Pete Hunts [`webpack-require`](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-require) but have been having difficulty with it.

Does anyone know of any other approaches that will work for this context?

---

**Update 2016/06/15**

Boom!  I've managed to pull this off without any 3rd party libs to help me.  `universal-webpack` is pretty cool and much cleaner than the previous `webpack-isomorphic-tools` but I am liking that I have a minimal configuration set up in which as little as possible of the universal webpack configuration bleeds into my production code.

I'm pretty stoked with the results.  Client bundle is backed by the lastest `react-hot-loader` v3 beta which is giving me an awesome HMR experience, and my Server bundle gets rebuilt on any file changes so not having to restart my server manually either.  Making for a pretty sweet development experience.

I am going to throw this into a boilerplate (yes I know, yet another) but perhaps it will be useful to someone else.

Comment: https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/universal-webpack

Comment: Thanks I was using his `webpack-isomorphic-tools` before but I didn't like the fact that a webpack compiler was being run within my server.  Looking at the source this is great as I can even target the server bundle without using this library too.  I prefer to keep the production code as clean as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: So what kind of answer you're looking for? If you want your environment to behave like webpack (and you do want it) - you either need a webpack or you need to implement something that behaves like webpack. There is no 3rd option.

Comment: Yep, I am happy with webpack being in my workflow, but I prefer to keep it within my development and deployment cycles, not within production runtime execution.  The `universal-webpack` library was very helpful in providing me some key points to understand about webpack in this scenario.

Comment: So how do you see a solution that requires webpack without webpack? Importing non-js resources is specifically a webpack feature.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you are misunderstanding me.  I am not trying to get rid of webpack, its just that I am not wanting webpack compilation to occur whilst my code is running in production.  I am happy to deploy my webpack output bundles to my server which do just work, and also wanted to have a dev server that did hot reloading of my webpack bundles when code changes occurred.  I completely understand webpack is necessary for me to produce the bundle output that will resolve the various non-js resources.

Comment: If you will find a solution please share it :-)

Comment: I do already have a working solution and do intend to share it. :)  I will let you know when it is cleaned up and ready.

Comment: @zerkms - as promised: https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a working solution achieving everything that I wanted from the configuration.

It's all within the following boilerplate repo:
https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally

Comment: I checked it briefly and it looks great! I'll try to use it with another tiny project that I need to get server-side rendering to.

Comment: I appreciate the positive feedback! :)  Please do let me know how your experience goes and whether you feel there are things that are lacking or that could be better explained.  I am going to create an expanded version of the boilerplate now that introduces an opinionated tech stack. It will be in a separate repo though.

Comment: I actually overlooked that it uses webpack2, which would prevent me from using for this very project :-(

Comment: @zerkms changing it to use webpack 1 is easy. :)

Comment: I'll create a branch for you. :)

Comment: Oh don't :-) Let me play with the `halt-hammerzeit/universal-webpack` first